# Crash on [liblog.so] LogdWrite(log_id, timespec*, iovec*, unsigned long)

Tags: android

I am seeing a following crash in my playstore account :

```
backtrace:
  #00  pc 0x00000000000008b8 
  #01  pc 0x000000000000d758  /system/lib64/liblog.so (LogdWrite(log_id, timespec*, iovec*, unsigned long)+528)
  #02  pc 0x00000000000065f0  /system/lib64/liblog.so (write_to_log(log_id, iovec*, unsigned long) (.__uniq.220335083604911598582518859745105420324)+184)
  #03  pc 0x000000000000650c  /system/lib64/liblog.so (__android_log_logd_logger+116)
  #04  pc 0x0000000000033ee4  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libbase.so (android::base::LogdLogChunk(android::base::LogId, android::base::LogSeverity, char const*, char const*)+136)
  #05  pc 0x0000000000033d54  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libbase.so (void android::base::SplitByLogdChunks<void (android::base::LogId, android::base::LogSeverity, char const*, char const*)>(android::base::LogId, android::base::LogSeverity, char const*, char const*, unsigned int, char const*, void  const(&)(android::base::LogId, android::base::LogSeverity, char const*, char const*))+716)
  #06  pc 0x0000000000035380  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libartbase.so (art::InitLogging(char**, void (&)(char const*))::LogdLoggerLocked::operator()(android::base::LogId, android::base::LogSeverity, char const*, char const*, unsigned int, char const*) (.__uniq.85101241731209538599761260233789784808)+112)
  #07  pc 0x000000000003565c  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libbase.so (android::base::SetLogger(std::__1::function<void (android::base::LogId, android::base::LogSeverity, char const*, char const*, unsigned int, char const*)>&&)::$_0::__invoke(__android_log_message const*)+188)
  #08  pc 0x000000000000691c  /system/lib64/liblog.so (__android_log_write_log_message+184)
  #09  pc 0x0000000000034f2c  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libbase.so (android::base::LogMessage::LogLine(char const*, unsigned int, android::base::LogSeverity, char const*, char const*)+132)
  #10  pc 0x0000000000034d20  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libbase.so (android::base::LogMessage::~LogMessage()+296)
  #11  pc 0x000000000001cee4  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libperfetto_hprof.so (perfetto_hprof::ForkAndRun(art::Thread*, perfetto_hprof::ResumeParentPolicy, std::__1::function<void (int)> const&, std::__1::function<void (int, unsigned long)> const&)+692)
  #12  pc 0x0000000000026544  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libperfetto_hprof.so (void* std::__1::__thread_proxy<std::__1::tuple<std::__1::unique_ptr<std::__1::__thread_struct, std::__1::default_delete<std::__1::__thread_struct> >, ArtPlugin_Initialize::$_7> >(void*)+368)
  #13  pc 0x00000000000be888  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+208)
  #14  pc 0x0000000000002370
```

I have very little knowlege on JNI. Can someone help what wrong going with my application popping up this kind of crash?

No Idea about the crash

Comment: Given that none of the stack trace entries are in your code, I think this can safely be ignored.